# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I was doing the tutorial from  the book teach yourself django in 24 hours and in part1 hour 4 i got stuck on this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 278, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 635, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 239, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 67, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 56, in process_request
    if (not _is_valid_path(request.path_info) and

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 142, in _is_valid_path
    urlresolvers.resolve(path)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 254, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 181, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 205, in _get_url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 200, in _get_urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = __import__(self.urlconf_name, {}, {}, [''])

  File "c:\projects\iFriends\..\iFriends\urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    (r'^admin/', include('django.contribute.admin.urls'))

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me please..

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

####Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
#### from django.contrib import admin
#### admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^People/$', 'iFriends.People.views.index') ,
    (r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')), 
    # Example:
    # (r'^iFriends/', include('iFriends.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:


)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You somehow set some function to a tuple. Please edit the question and paste your `urls.py` code, so we can point you to the error.

I can try a **wild guess**:

```
File "c:\projects\iFriends\..\iFriends\urls.py", line 17, in <module>
   (r'^admin/', include('django.contribute.admin.urls'))
```

This somehow tells me that you missed a comma on line 16, so:

```
16. (r'^/', 'some_stuff....')      # <-- missed comma here
17. (r'^admin/', include('django.contribute.admin.urls'))
```

Just put the comma and it will work. If that's not the case, I'll send my cristal ball for mainantance. Paste the code.

## EDIT

Seems like you have pasted the `urls.py` as an answer. Please edit the **question** and paste urls.py there.

Anyway, the error has changed. What did you do? In this new error, `urls.py` is not found anymore so maybe you've renamed it? Have you changed the way you run the application?

The file you pasted **is not** the one that is running. Are you pasting `url.py` and django is reading `urls.py`? The code in the error doesn't match the code you pasted! Please paste the correct file, i.e. the same that gives the error, or we can't help.